# Merging Contacts Records fails

Tags: duplicate-contacts

Running Drupal 7.59, CiviCRM 5.8.1 and PHP 7.1.26. After selecting two known duplicate records from a list and selecting the action "Merge Contacts", I receive the following error message.

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: no such field

We migrated from one hosting site to another approximately three weeks ago and have been unable to merge any records since then. I don't know if this could be the reason but it should be considered.
I have tried to merge different Types of Contacts (Individuals, Organizations) but the result is always the same - "DB Error: no such field".
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check CiviCRM logs for more details of "DB Error: no such field" error and add it to your post?

Comment: I enabled debugging and backtrace and repeated my merge efforts, this the detailed error response:

Comment: Did you miss to add the error details?

Comment: Is this the same problem as in this post?
https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/29210/dedupe-using-postcode-match-db-error-array

Comment: I don't think it would be - that specific problem is only in 5.12.