# Dedupe using postcode match - DB error - Array

Tags: duplicate-contacts

We have a similar error to [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28179/merging-contacts-records-fails), but with Joomla 5.9.2 and CiviCRM 5.12.0. Error happens when trying to merge two contacts with Postcode match.
Backtrace is below. Any ideas what could be causing this error? Thanks.

```
    #0 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(232): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
    #1 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
    #2 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no such field", -19, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT t1.contact_id id1, t2.contact_id...")
    #3 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-19, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT t1.contact_id id1, t2.contact_id...")
    #4 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -19, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT t1.contact_id id1, t2.contact_id...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
    #5 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1907): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
    #6 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, "INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT t1.contact_id id1, t2.contact_id...", "1054 ** Unknown column 'Array' in 'on clause'")
    #7 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
    #8 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT t1.contact_id id1, t2.contact_id...")
    #9 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2415): DB_common->query("INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT t1.contact_id id1, t2.contact_id...")
    #10 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1607): DB_DataObject->_query("INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT t1.contact_id id1, t2.contact_id...")
    #11 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(438): DB_DataObject->query("INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT t1.contact_id id1, t2.contact_id...")
    #12 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/BAO/RuleGroup.php(281): CRM_Core_DAO->query("INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT t1.contact_id id1, t2.contact_id...")
    #13 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Finder.php(81): CRM_Dedupe_BAO_RuleGroup->fillTable()
    #14 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/PrevNextCache.php(414): CRM_Dedupe_Finder::dupes("2", (Array:0), TRUE, NULL)
    #15 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php(1996): CRM_Core_BAO_PrevNextCache::refillCache("2", NULL, "merge_Organization_2_0_0_46533", (Array:0), TRUE, NULL)
    #16 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/DedupeFind.php(185): CRM_Dedupe_Merger::getDuplicatePairs("2", NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, "", FALSE, (Array:0), TRUE, NULL)
    #17 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(309): CRM_Contact_Page_DedupeFind->run((Array:3), NULL)
    #18 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
    #19 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
    #20 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(121): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
    #21 site_root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke()
    #22 site_root/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(402): require_once("site_root/administrator/components/com_civic...")
    #23 site_root/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(377): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent("site_root/administrator/components/com_civic...")
    #24 site_root/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(101): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
    #25 site_root/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(159): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch()
    #26 site_root/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php(196): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()
    #27 site_root/administrator/index.php(51): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
    #28 {main}
```

Error in log (formatting's a bit wonky - should all be one block):

```
[info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
```

(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28179/merging-contacts-records-fails) => handle
        )

```
[code] => -19
[message] => DB Error: no such field
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT t1.contact_id id1, t2.contact_id id2, 10 weight FROM civicrm_address t1 INNER JOIN civicrm_address t2 ON (t1.postal_code IS NOT NULL AND t2.postal_code IS NOT NULL AND t1.postal_code = t2.postal_code AND t1.postal_code <> '' AND t2.postal_code <> '' AND Array) WHERE t1.contact_id < t2.contact_id GROUP BY id1, id2, weight ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight) [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'Array' in 'on clause']
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT t1.contact_id id1, t2.contact_id id2, 10 weight FROM civicrm_address t1 INNER JOIN civicrm_address t2 ON (t1.postal_code IS NOT NULL AND t2.postal_code IS NOT NULL AND t1.postal_code = t2.postal_code AND t1.postal_code <> '' AND t2.postal_code <> '' AND Array) WHERE t1.contact_id < t2.contact_id GROUP BY id1, id2, weight ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight) [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'Array' in 'on clause']
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such field" code=-19 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT t1.contact_id id1, t2.contact_id id2, 10 weight FROM civicrm_address t1 INNER JOIN civicrm_address t2 ON (t1.postal_code IS NOT NULL AND t2.postal_code IS NOT NULL AND t1.postal_code = t2.postal_code AND t1.postal_code <> '' AND t2.postal_code <> '' AND Array) WHERE t1.contact_id < t2.contact_id GROUP BY id1, id2, weight ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight) [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'Array' in 'on clause']"]
```

)

Comment: The problem is the part that says `"1054 ** Unknown column 'Array' in 'on clause'"`. Are you able to put in some debugging around line 281 in CRM/Dedupe/BAO/RuleGroup.php to see what the full query is? Something is being evaluated as an array instead of a string.

Comment: Query looks like this: INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT t1.contact_id id1, t2.contact_id id2, 10 weight FROM civicrm_address t1 INNER JOIN civicrm_address t2 ON (t1.postal_code IS NOT NULL AND t2.postal_code IS NOT NULL AND t1.postal_code = t2.postal_code AND t1.postal_code <> '' AND t2.postal_code <> '' AND Array) WHERE t1.contact_id < t2.contact_id GROUP BY id1, id2, weight ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight)

Comment: What is URN? Is that a custom field? Something multivalued maybe?

Comment: I don't think URN is relevant. We get the error if we just dedupe with postal codes. Then $tableQueries looks like this:
Array([civicrm_address.postal_code.10] => SELECT t1.contact_id id1, t2.contact_id id2, 10 weight FROM civicrm_address t1 INNER JOIN civicrm_address t2 ON (t1.postal_code IS NOT NULL AND t2.postal_code IS NOT NULL AND t1.postal_code = t2.postal_code AND t1.postal_code <> '' AND t2.postal_code <> '' AND Array) WHERE t1.contact_id < t2.contact_id)

Comment: Are you able to debug around line 177 - find out what is generating "Array"?

Comment: The same:
[info] $queries: Array
(
    [civicrm_address.postal_code.10] => SELECT t1.contact_id id1, t2.contact_id id2, 10 weight FROM civicrm_address t1 INNER JOIN civicrm_address t2 ON (t1.postal_code IS NOT NULL AND t2.postal_code IS NOT NULL AND t1.postal_code = t2.postal_code AND t1.postal_code <> '' AND t2.postal_code <> '' AND Array) WHERE t1.contact_id < t2.contact_id
)

Comment: $bao: CRM_Dedupe_BAO_Rule Object
(
    [contactIds] => Array
        (
        )

    [params] => Array
        (
        )

    [id] => 121
    [dedupe_rule_group_id] => 11
    [rule_table] => civicrm_address
    [rule_field] => postal_code
    [rule_length] => 
    [rule_weight] => 10
    [resultCopies:protected] => 0
    [_options:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_DB_DataObject_version] => 1.8.12
    [__table] => civicrm_dedupe_rule
    [N] => 1
    [_database_dsn] => 
    [_database_dsn_md5] => 

truncated

Comment: I see what the problem is. Will post answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Dedupe/BAO/Rule.php#L110

Instead of

`$innerJoinClauses[] = ['t1.location_type_id = t2.location_type_id'];`

it should be

`$innerJoinClauses[] = 't1.location_type_id = t2.location_type_id';`

EDIT: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14013

Comment: Yes, that's done it. Brilliant. Thanks!